# Get All Pre orders from Magento

Tags: orders

How can I get all orders using Resy API with status as Pre Orders?
I tried using Get Orders but not sure which status will reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a query parameter to filter by status making the call like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0]field]=status
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=your_status_code
```

Let me know if this solved your problem.